# Issue in automatically updating the URL when monitoring

Tags: c#

We have created a Windows service for monitoring an URL to receive data daily (getting the rate from the parent website and we will update the same in our project on daily basis). The services is installed in both the local system and also in the production server.
The rates are getting updated regularly on time in the parent website but, when we get the rates from the parent website URL, there is a time delay for us even though we are monitoring the URL every minute.
E.g., we get rates at local system at 07:00 PM and on the server we get the rates on 11:00 PM, but the actual updating time on the parent website is 06:00 PM daily.

Can any one give us the solution to solve this issue?

Code what we have used

```
string url = "http://dummyurl/path/test/test.zip";          
CheckDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "\\foldername");
string logFilePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\foldername\\filename.Zip";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 50000;         
try
{
    using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();                     
        }
    }

    CheckDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "\\Extract");
    string extract = Application.StartupPath + "\\Extract\\";

    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(logFilePath))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".csv", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(extract, entry.FullName)))
                {
                    File.Delete(Path.Combine(extract, entry.FullName));
                }
                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extract, entry.FullName));    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have installed Windows service and we have set up to monitor every minute:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) 
{
    timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
    timer1.Interval = 60000; 
    timer1.Enabled = true; 
    timer1.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: how do you obtain the request log on the server? If it is an IIS and you are using its built-in logging, you will see times in UTC. the other offset you observe, the one hour off, smells like an additional daylight savings time. what is your local time zone?

Comment: The time difference what we have mentioned is just an example, sometimes it may takes more than an hour also.

Comment: ok. from where, exactly, do you read those timestamps? file creation times, file access times, logs, which logs?

Comment: We have installed window services and we have set up to monitor for every minute,                                                                             
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
            timer1.Interval = 60000;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

Comment: that would just count hours relative to any given starting time. I don't get the big picture of what you're trying to achieve here yet. Please write all information about your time measurements into the question, maybe then someone will be able to help. IMO the download-and-extract code shown is not related to the actual question.

Comment: I think it's quite rude how you just roll back the changes from dlatikay. It was a real improvement to the original question in terms of grammar and formatting. If you can't appreciate the work of others, please improve the question yourself in these regards.